# How to find if the sequence $(x^n)$ is monotonically increasing or decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

How do I say that whether the sequence $(x^n),x \in [0,1]$, $n \in N$ is monotonically increasing or decreasing using differentiation ?

I know that for $x^n$ to be monotonically decreasing $f'\le 0$ The book says $x^n$ is monotonically decreasing but i am not able to see how.

Comment: What is $f'(x)$? (And the book should say monotonically increasing [for $n > 0$].)

Comment: Perhaps you mean the *sequence* $(x^n)$ is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: That certainly makes more sense, @David.

Comment: @DavidMitra yes, its sequence $(x^n)$ does it make a difference ? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Indeed it does. Here, you consider $x$ fixed. Then the sequence $(x^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is decreasing. This is true for each $x\in[0,1]$; so the sequence of functions $(x^n)$ is said to be "decreasing".

Comment: @DavidMitra like say $x=0.5$ and when this is raise to higher powers it decreases. okie. i think i get it. So if there are more complex functions like ${x^n}\over {1+x^n}$ so we deduce by reasoning or is their a standard way like differentiation works in algebraic functions ?

Comment: Usually it's ad-hoc. But if things are well-defined, you can differentiate with respect to the variable $n$. Here ${d\over dn} x^n=(\ln x) x^n<0$ for $0<x<1$ (of course this is silly to do for this sequence).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks a lot. Please post it as an answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you consider $x$  to be fixed. Then, as easily seen (see the comments above), the sequence $(x^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a decreasing sequence of reals. This is true for each $x\in [0,1]$; so the sequence of functions $(x_n)$ is said to be "decreasing".

(You can differentiate with respect to the variable $n$ to show $(x^n)$ is decreasing. Here ${d\over dn} x^n=(\ln x) x^n<0$ for $0<x<1$ (of course this is silly to do for this sequence).)

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $f_n(x)=x^n,\,\forall\,x\in[0,1]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is:

$$f'_n(x)=nx^{n-1}.$$

You have, $n\ge0$ and $\forall\,x\in[0, 1]$, $x^{n-1}\ge0$. Therefore:

$$f'_n(x)\ge0.$$

Thus, $f_n(x)=x^n$ is monotonically increasing in $[0, 1]$ and $n$ a positive number (not decreasing).